# AJAX Email send doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

Ok so I want to submit a form without reloading the page, probably this is an old topic. However, I managed to find the solution but it simply doesn't work and I don't know what I am missing.

I know that it is a javascript problem because if I use the simple version, submitting the form without any javascript, I receive the email, but now I don't.

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="confirm.php" id="support" method="post">
    <input autocomplete="off" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Numele tău" required="" type="text" />
    <input autocomplete="off" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email-ul tău" required="" type="email" />
    <input autocomplete="off" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Numărul tău de telefon (opțional)" type="tel" />
    <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="TRIMITE" />
    <p id="success">Thanks!</p>
</form>
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $to = "invest@es-sphere.ro";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $from = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];

        $subject = "Sunt interesat de INVEST!";

        $message = $name . ", cu numărul de telefon " . $phone . " și email-ul " . $from . "este interesat de proiectul INVEST";

        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
?>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#support').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.post("confirm.php", formData).done(function() {
        console.log("Success");
        $("#success").show();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that you are checking if "submit" has been sent. But the button value doesn't get sent with your existing code.

Change this

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

to

`if(isset($_POST['name'])){`

Or some other value, or probably best, check for all values.

Comment: Wow, I can't belive that this is what I missed :)) Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).serialize()` will not gather the name/value of the submit button used to submit the form.

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` will therefore fail.

Use some other test (e.g. another field) to see if form data is being submitted.